# How can two condition works in if-ifelse-else statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

My professor shows the following example in C:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
   pid_t pid;

   /* fork another process */
   pid = fork();
   if (pid < 0) { /* error occurred */
         fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
         return 1;
   }
   else if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
         execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
   }
   else { /* parent process */
        /* parent will wait for the child */
        wait (NULL);
        printf("Child Completed its execution\n");
   }

return 0;
}
```

I compiled it and ran it. I saw a strange behavior in this code:

The result of 'ls' program/command is printed which is in the else if condition but also the string "Child Completed its execution\n" printed too which is in else.

Isn't this a strange behavior?

Comment: When you see a function that you don't know, always check the manual about it ! There is no dark magic in there. A little glance over there should enlighten you http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you forked it. There are two processes running. One reported the ls and the other reported the printf().

Specifically, the child/forked process executed /bin/ls and the parent called printf(), the output you see.

Comment: Do you mean that the child checks the condition of else if and it is true in the child's side. The parent also checks the same condition but it is false on its side then it fall into 'else'? So I am having two processes using the if-statement and instructions?

Comment: Yes, each process (the parent) and the fork, are executing the same code. The child process (the one that is created when you call fork()) will have a pid of zero, and therefor that condition will be true. The parent, will have a a pid of XXXX (>0), and therefor satisfy the last condition.

Comment: I have placed a printf statement before return 0 but it was executed once. When does the fork terminated in my code? Does execlp terminated the child?

Comment: I don't know - the if you placed a final printf() it should be executed by both the child and parent ...

Comment: `execlp` replaces the code of the process with another executable (in this case `ls`) and never returns, so the child will never see the `printf`.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that about execlp(), never used it.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `fork` creates a child process which continues executing from the same point in the code, but with `pid` set to 0. What you were seeing is the parent process executing the `printf` line, while the child process was executing the `ls` command.